# Reload js behaviors after click

Tags: views, javascript, ajax, search, bootstrap-theme

I'm using boostrap 3 with modals. I've a button that opens a modal, in the modal there are some facet blocks.
The view has ajax enabled, so when I click on a facet the page is not reload but are reloaded the content of the view AND facets blocks.

I've to execute some js functions when I click on facets links, I've added this js to my theme:

```
Drupal.behaviors.my_theme = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
        jQuery('#facets a', context).click(function () {
            alert('enter');
        });
    }
};
```

The problem is that the alert is executed only on the first click. On second, third etc alert does not appear.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if the ID has changed. If the content containing #facets is getting ajaxed in then the ID may have changed

Or you could try:

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '#facets a', function () {
        alert('enter');
    });
```

Comment: Yes it works, thanks. The problem now is that, after the second click, "alert" is executed many times. On every click I've to append a loading-spinner to the html

Comment: However I found a trick, but the problem that the code is execute many times..

Comment: You could try adding .once like:  jQuery('body').once('facet-clicked').on('click', '#facets a', function () {